# Sympy solver exclude result

Tags: sympy, solver, boundary

I would like to know if it is possible with Sympy to solve simple equation of this kind not especially this one:

```
sol = solve(x**2)
```

but with conditions like for example  :

- sol[0] < n (n is a real number )
- sol[0] != n
- m < sol[0] < n (m is a real number too)

And if i can put the same condition for

```
Product( k, (k, 1, 3) ).doit()
```

And other if it is possible.

Thanks.

Read documentation for hours and found nothing.

Look on stackoverflow and else where on the internet

And i am kind of not an expert so i found those and was not sure if it answer my question because i did not understand what they say:

- [sympy eliminate or chancel unwanted results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960645/sympy-eliminate-or-chancel-unwanted-results)
- [Is there anyway I can exclude some of the solutions of sympy solver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752234/is-there-anyway-i-can-exclude-some-of-the-solutions-of-sympy-solver)
- [SymPy integration with assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219860/sympy-integration-with-assumptions)
- [Assuming a symbol is between zero and one with SymPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959174/assuming-a-symbol-is-between-zero-and-one-with-sympy)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to answer well. Is it a univariate expression you are trying to solve? Do you expect a closed form solution? You can use `solveset` and give it the domain in which to search for a solution,

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x,n
>>> solveset(x**2-1, x, Interval(0,3))
{1}
>>> solveset(x**2-1, x, (x<3).as_set())
{-1, 1}
```

I don't know what you want to try to do with the Product, but

```py
>>> Product( k, (k, 1, 3) ).doit() < n
6 < n
>>> Product( k, (k, 1, 3) ).doit() < 1
False
```